# When centering dialog, first appears on topleft corner for some milliseconds

Tags: java, swt, composite

I'm generating a dialog with a lot of content. I want to pack the dialog to the childrens height, and I want to center it on screen, so I'm doing this after adding all the childrens:

```
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        shell.pack(); //for wrap the dialog size to it's content width and height.

        //the dialog must be centered after doing shell.pack();
        Rectangle parentSize = getParent().getBounds();
        Rectangle shellSize = shell.getBounds();
        int x = parentSize.x + (parentSize.width - shellSize.width) / 2;
        int y = (int) (parentSize.y + (parentSize.height - shellSize.height) / 3.5);
        shell.setLocation(new Point(x, y));
```

The problem is that for some milliseconds the dialog is being visible with a lot of width and on the top left corner of the screen. I tried doing setVisible(false) and (true) to shell to do the trick but it doesn't works.

How can I avoid to see the dialog on the top left corner and with a lot of width for some milliseconds?

This is the full code:

```
public class SelectTwoMatrixNumbersDialog extends Dialog {
    protected ArrayList<Integer> matrixNumbers1;
    protected ArrayList<Integer> matrixNumbers2;
    protected Shell shell;
    private JointBet jointBet;
    private boolean result; 
    NumbersMatrixWidget numbersMatrixWidget1;
    NumbersMatrixWidget numbersMatrixWidget2;

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     * @param parent
     * @param style
     */
    public SelectTwoMatrixNumbersDialog(Shell parent, int style, JointBet jointBet) {
        super(parent, style);
        setText("Elegir Números");
        this.jointBet = jointBet;
    }

    /**
     * Open the dialog.
     * @return the result
     */
    public boolean open() {
        createContents();

        matrixNumbers1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        matrixNumbers2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        GridLayout gl_shell = new GridLayout(1, false);
        gl_shell.marginWidth = 20;
        gl_shell.marginHeight = 20;
        shell.setLayout(gl_shell);

        Composite contentComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        contentComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        contentComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 1));

        Label lblNumbers = new Label(contentComposite, SWT.NONE);
        lblNumbers.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        lblNumbers.setText("Números:");

        Composite numbersContainerComposite = new Composite(contentComposite, SWT.NONE);
        numbersContainerComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));

        //variable values depending of type of game
        boolean firstCellEmpty = jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[0].isFirstCellEmpty();      
        int matrix1Rows = jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[0].getRows();
        int matrix1Columns = jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[0].getColumns();
        int matrix1MinNumber = jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[0].getMinNumber();
        int matrix1MaxNumber = jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[0].getMaxNumber();        
        GridLayout gl_numbersContainerComposite = new GridLayout(2, false);
        gl_numbersContainerComposite.horizontalSpacing = 15;
        numbersContainerComposite.setLayout(gl_numbersContainerComposite);
        numbersMatrixWidget1 = new NumbersMatrixWidget(numbersContainerComposite, SWT.BORDER, false, jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[0].getNumbers(), matrix1Rows, matrix1Columns, matrix1MinNumber, matrix1MaxNumber, firstCellEmpty);

        //variable values depending of type of game
        firstCellEmpty = jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[1].isFirstCellEmpty();      
        int matrix2Rows = jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[1].getRows();
        int matrix2Columns = jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[1].getColumns();
        int matrix2MinNumber = jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[1].getMinNumber();
        int matrix2MaxNumber = jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[1].getMaxNumber();
        numbersMatrixWidget2 = new NumbersMatrixWidget(numbersContainerComposite, SWT.BORDER, false, jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[1].getNumbers(), matrix2Rows, matrix2Columns, matrix2MinNumber, matrix2MaxNumber, firstCellEmpty);
        numbersMatrixWidget2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.BOTTOM, false, false, 1, 1));

        Composite fillNumbersComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        fillNumbersComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1));
        fillNumbersComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Composite compositeFillMatrix1 = new Composite(fillNumbersComposite, SWT.NONE);
        compositeFillMatrix1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));

        Label lblFillMatrix1WithMostCommonNumbers1 = new Label(compositeFillMatrix1, SWT.NONE);
        lblFillMatrix1WithMostCommonNumbers1.setText("Rellenar Matriz 1 con los");

        Spinner matrix1NumbersSpinner = new Spinner(compositeFillMatrix1, SWT.BORDER);
        matrix1NumbersSpinner.setMaximum(jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[0].getPossibleNumbersCount());
        matrix1NumbersSpinner.setMinimum(1);

        Label lblFillMatrix1WithMostCommonNumbers2 = new Label(compositeFillMatrix1, SWT.NONE);
        lblFillMatrix1WithMostCommonNumbers2.setText("números mas repetidos:");

        Button btnFillMatrix1 = new Button(compositeFillMatrix1, SWT.NONE);
        btnFillMatrix1.setText("Rellenar");
        btnFillMatrix1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                String gameType = jointBet.getGameType().getType();
                int matrix = 1;
                int amount = Integer.parseInt(matrix1NumbersSpinner.getText());
                numbersMatrixWidget1.setNumbers(StatisticsManager.getInstance().getMostUsedNumberKeys(gameType, matrix, amount));
            }
        });

        Composite compositeFillMatrix2 = new Composite(fillNumbersComposite, SWT.NONE);
        compositeFillMatrix2.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));

        Label lblFillMatrix2WithMostCommonNumbers1 = new Label(compositeFillMatrix2, SWT.NONE);
        lblFillMatrix2WithMostCommonNumbers1.setText("Rellenar Matriz 2 con los");

        Spinner matrix2NumbersSpinner = new Spinner(compositeFillMatrix2, SWT.BORDER);
        matrix2NumbersSpinner.setMaximum(jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[1].getPossibleNumbersCount());
        matrix2NumbersSpinner.setMinimum(1);

        Label lblFillMatrix2WithMostCommonNumbers2 = new Label(compositeFillMatrix2, SWT.NONE);
        lblFillMatrix2WithMostCommonNumbers2.setText("números mas repetidos:");

        Button btnFillMatrix2 = new Button(compositeFillMatrix2, SWT.NONE);
        btnFillMatrix2.setText("Rellenar");
        btnFillMatrix2.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                String gameType = jointBet.getGameType().getType();
                int matrix = 2;
                int amount = Integer.parseInt(matrix2NumbersSpinner.getText());
                numbersMatrixWidget2.setNumbers(StatisticsManager.getInstance().getMostUsedNumberKeys(gameType, matrix, amount));
            }
        });

        Composite buttonsComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        FillLayout fl_buttonsComposite = new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL);
        fl_buttonsComposite.marginHeight = 10;
        fl_buttonsComposite.spacing = 40;
        buttonsComposite.setLayout(fl_buttonsComposite);
        GridData gd_buttonsComposite = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
        gd_buttonsComposite.heightHint = 45;
        buttonsComposite.setLayoutData(gd_buttonsComposite);

        Button acceptButton = new Button(buttonsComposite, SWT.NONE);
        acceptButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {  
                //matrix 1
                matrixNumbers1.clear();
                for (Button b : numbersMatrixWidget1.getButtons()) {
                    if (b.getSelection()) {
                        matrixNumbers1.add(Integer.parseInt(b.getText()));
                    }
                }

                //matrix 2
                matrixNumbers2.clear();
                for (Button b : numbersMatrixWidget2.getButtons()) {
                    if (b.getSelection()) {
                        matrixNumbers2.add(Integer.parseInt(b.getText()));
                    }
                }

                if (matrixNumbers1.size()<jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[0].getNumbersPerBet() || matrixNumbers2.size()<jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[1].getNumbersPerBet()) {
                    ErrorDialog dialog = new ErrorDialog(shell, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL, "El mínimo de números es "+jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[0].getNumbersPerBet()+" + "+jointBet.getGameType().getNumbersMatrixArray()[1].getNumbersPerBet());
                    dialog.open();
                }else {                 
                    Collections.sort(matrixNumbers1);
                    Collections.sort(matrixNumbers2);

                    jointBet.setNumbers(0, matrixNumbers1);
                    jointBet.setNumbers(1, matrixNumbers2);
                    DataManager.getInstance().saveData();

                    result = true;
                    shell.close();
                }
            }
        });
        acceptButton.setBounds(0, 0, 75, 25);
        acceptButton.setText("Aceptar");

        Button cancelButton = new Button(buttonsComposite, SWT.NONE);
        cancelButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                result = false;
                shell.close();
            }
        });
        cancelButton.setBounds(0, 0, 75, 25);
        cancelButton.setText("Cancelar");

        shell.setDefaultButton(acceptButton);

        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        shell.pack(); //for wrap the dialog size to it's content width and height.

        //the dialog must be centered after doing shell.pack();
        Rectangle parentSize = getParent().getBounds();
        Rectangle shellSize = shell.getBounds();
        int x = parentSize.x + (parentSize.width - shellSize.width) / 2;
        int y = (int) (parentSize.y + (parentSize.height - shellSize.height) / 3.5);
        shell.setLocation(new Point(x, y));

        Display display = getParent().getDisplay();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the dialog.
     */
    private void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell(getParent(), getStyle());
        shell.setText(getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `shell.open()` to the end of the size calculations - after the `shell.setLocation`.

Comment: thank you very much greg-449 your support here for SWT is amazing. Are you working for IBM as SWT supporter or something similar? or you do this in your free time just for help the community?